# How do you detect what URL the user typed in to connect to your server?

Tags: java, networking, telnet

I am making a telnet server using Java, and I want to detect which domain the user connected from. In my case, I have 3 domains (`example.com`, `example.net`, and `example.org`) that all point to my IP, and I want to host a different server for all of them. I need to detect which domain they connected to, so I can send a different message.

I know the Apache webserver does something similar with VirtualHosts, and was wondering how to do this in Java.

Comment: Apache knows what domain the client entered by looking at the HTTP headers. There is no such thing in the `Telnet` protocol.

Comment: What a Web-server can do is not necessarily relevant, since they get that information from the `Host:` request header (which HTTP/1.1 clients are required to include). I don't know whether Telnet includes anything analogous, but I rather doubt it. :-/

Comment: The user didn't type any URL to connect to your Telnet server. He typed a hostname or IP address, and a port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really.

Apache is able to support this using Virtual Hosts because the HTTP protocol includes a host header in the content of the request which the browser fills in with the host portion of the URL. (see section 14.23 of [rfc-2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

Telnet doesn't, as far as I know, include such a header. best place to check would be [rfc-854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854)

Comment: Thanks! I'm rather disappointed about that, I guess I need to just host it on different ports. Or have the user choose which they want. Thanks anyways. Also, I read through that RFC page, and it doesn't say anything about an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The *HTTP protocol* is closely related to domain names and is more likely to fit your needs if you are building a `Telnet` server. It is a rock-solid and a well improved protocol.

In this case, why not using `HTTP` instead of the deprecated `Telnet` protocol ?

The advantages here would be :

- HTTP handles all the data you need. You will be able to easily build more complex applications having access to a wider range of metadata.
- The ability to use the numerous HTTP stack available for Java, such as [Apache common's HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/)
- The compatibility, as many apps will be already able to send/receive requests to your server.
- The scalability, as it will be possible to extend your server as your needs will change. Take for example the situation where you will need to secure a stream between your server and a client. HTTPS support is embedded in most HTTP stacks for Java.
- At last, it will allow you to know form which domain a client made his request.

Comment: I don't really have any _real_ reasons, but I like the idea of Telnet better. I guess I like how retro it is. I saw a bunch of talkers like [Nuts](http://www.ogham.demon.co.uk/nuts.html) and [Amnuts](https://github.com/amnuts/Amnuts), and I decided I wanted to code my own. That's really my only reason. If you look through my history of questions, most of the Java ones were just for this project.

Comment: All right. Then I guess you might have to write a small protocol on top of telnet to know which hostname the client made his query from, if you're writing both client and servers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm writing _only_ server, so, as I said in my comment to the other answer, I'll probably have to host them on different ports, or have the user select which one they want.

Comment: HTTP is not an adequate alternative or replacement for the 'deprecated Telnet protocol'. The Telnet protocol is not 'deprecated'. HTTP is a request-response protocol; Telnet is a bidirectional terminal protocol. The two are not commensurable, although Telnet over HTTP implementations certainly exist. And work badly. -1

Comment: I was responding to the need @HobbitHole evoked, and listed the benefits of using HTTP for HIS needs. The fact that HTTP is stateless and a telnet session is bidirectional is totally irrelevant here, as the response was meant to guide this user in what he might want to implement. Like Angelo Genovese pointed out, what he wants to achieve is impossible, or very difficult using Telnet. So HTTP, might be a good option.